# go/golang + redis too many open files error

Tags: redis, go

I'm using redis in Golang with the Redigo connector (https://github.com/garyburd/redigo) suggested by the Redis website.

I have:

- After every Dial() I defer a Close()
- Set fs.file-max = 100000
- Set vm.overcommit_memory = 1
- Disabled saving
- Set maxclients = 100000

I run a high traffic website, and everything runs great for about 10 minutes, from which I get

```
error: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6379: too many open files
```

Then I can't access redis at all from my application.

I see nothing in the redis logs to suggest any errors or problems. What do I do to fix this?

Comment: Run `lsof|wc -l` to get a count of all open files. You can compare the number of open files against the `ulimit` value. More info: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-find-all-file-descriptors-used-by-a-process/ and http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know which driver you use but with [redigo](https://github.com/garyburd/redigo) you can define a number of open connections in a pool, all you have to do then is in every query to redis, first get a client from the pool, then close it, so it goes back to the pool and gets re-used, just like this:

```
redisPool = &redis.Pool{
        MaxIdle: 3,
        MaxActive: 10, // max number of connections
        Dial: func() (redis.Conn, error) {
                c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", ":6379")
                if err != nil {
                        panic(err.Error())
                }
                return c, err
        },
}
r := redisPool.Get() // get a client from the pool
_, err = r.Do("GET one") // use the client
if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
}
r.Close() // close the client so the connection gets reused
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! This is perfect!! Does this mean when doing an HTTP web application, I should make a global pointer to the Pool? Then just pull from this global pointer.

Comment: I think so, don't see a lot of implications with it.. If you want to contain access in some parts of the code then you can make distinct pools in distinct contexts, that should be fine as well..

Comment: A better way to close the connection would be `defer r.Close()` after `r := redisPool.Get()`

Comment: FYI, this is outdated answer now, as there is no redis.Pool

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that Redis cant open new connections and then becomes unresponsive, you need to increase the file descriptors limit of your operating system (ubuntu defaults to 1024 which can be a problem) which right now is dominating the redis maxclients setting.

The way you tweak this limit depends on the os redis is running, on linux you need something like this:

```
ulimit -n 99999
```

Comment: This may work temporarily, but if you run a program long enough, then it may hit the limit.  The risk to raising ulimit is that it works on dev box, but in production, with higher request rates and run time, you hit the problem.  There are times you need to raise ulimit, so your answer is useful to some people, but in my case, I need to prevent so many files being opened.

Comment: @thebiggestlebowski I agree with you, if your program leaks connections or does the wrong thing, you should fix that. That being said, the 1024 max limit on most Linux is incredibly low, many healthy programs running in production will crash or worse because of it.